# Driver support and general knowledge needed

Tags: networking, drivers, games, icc

Am a new user to Linux as the only distri I tried was mint and I had a realll] hard time on it when it comes to drivers

From Google search it says that with Ubuntu I don't have to use terminal command at all but am concerned as mentioned coming from windows which I spent my life of but really got sick of it after win10.

Now if have a few questions if it's not  too much to ask.

- how is the driver support for a rig like this
  2600x . GTX 1650. A 144hz monitor that needs ICC. M2 drive.
- am I gonna need terminal command when it comes to fixing resulotion or refresh rate or applying ICC.
- is Nvidia control panel access able like the one in windows.
- is there any other concerns I should worry about when it comes to dealing with Ubuntu for a complete Linux noob.

Thank you

Comment: Nvidia drivers can be installed using Software & Updates > Additional Drivers. Nvidia's control panel is installed alongside.

Comment: Thank you.what about applying icc profiles. Is it possible in Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know about that but it certainly can be a good question on its own. As this isn't a forum I suggest you post a new specific question about that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please ask one question at a time. See the site help for guidance.

Comment: The Ubuntu installer includes a Live environment so you can test your hardware and test-drive Ubuntu BEFORE committing to an install. Try the Live environment first, then use the 'Search' box at the top of each AskUbuntu page to see if anybody has already asked the question, and what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

> how is the driver support for a rig like this 2600x . GTX 1650. A 144hz monitor that needs ICC. M2 drive.

You get a GENERIC driver installed when installing and have the option of some proprietary drivers. From 19.10 onwards the proprietary driver will be included on the installer.

> am I gonna need terminal command when it comes to fixing resulotion or refresh rate or applying ICC.

Maybe. terminal is the best feature ever. If you start like this you Ubuntu experience is going to be bad ;) Open your mind! Embrace the terminal. You will learn so many things about your system through command line.

> is Nvidia control panel access

Yes there is a control panel. Example:

[image]

> able like the one in windows.

We don't know what Windows uses as a control panel.

> is there any other concerns I should worry about when it comes to dealing with Ubuntu for a complete Linux noob.

- Do not compare it to Windows, Linux is set up from the ground up as a multi-user system and therefor has tools to enforce this. "sudo" being one of those tools.
- Do not fight against tools in Linux. With the live session comming in at a 2nd place command line is the BEST FEATURE EVER. In Linux you can fix almost every mistake you make through command line.
- Use virtualization; that way you can still use Windows and can get used to Ubuntu.